# xindy and location attribute priority

Tags: xindy

With this MWE idx file:

```
\indexentry{chat!sauvage}{1}
\indexentry{chat!sauvage}{2}
\indexentry{chat!sauvage}{3}
\indexentry{chat!sauvage|textbf}{3}
```

I obtain, with `texindex -L french`, the following line in the .ind file :

```
\subitem sauvage, 1--3
```

While I prefer

```
\subitem sauvage, 1, 2, \textbf{3}
```

which keepts the `texbf`.

I have overriden the default `latex-loc-fmts.xdy` by creating one file with the same name in my local directory.

It's content is

```
(define-attributes (( "textbf" "textit" "hyperpage" "default")))

(markup-locref :open "\textbf{" :close "}" :attr "textbf")
(markup-locref :open "\textit{" :close "}" :attr "textit")
(markup-locref :open "\hyperpage{" :close "}" :attr "hyperpage")
```

Is there another solution to define attribut priority than override this file ?